# infinite scroll working but not populating all data because of javascript call

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates, infinite-scroll

In my web site I want to show the user ratings - for that I used the infinite scroll but I am facing one problem.

When it first loads the data before calling the `<a class="infinite-more-link" href="?page={{ ratings.next_page_number }}"></a>` it is showing the star with the count of vote,but when after calling the `<a class="infinite-more-link" href="?page={{ ratings.next_page_number }}"></a>` it is not showing the star.

my views.py

```
@login_required
def ratings_user(request,pk):
    ratings = VoteUser.objects.filter(the_user_id=pk).order_by('-pk')
    paginator = Paginator(ratings, 1)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:

        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request,request.session['is_mobile']+'profile/ratings.html',{'ratings':posts})
```

html

```
{% extends 'mobile/profile/base.html' %}
{% block title %}
Ratings
{% endblock %}

{% block leftcontent %}
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock %}
{% block middlecontent %}
 <div class="infinite-container">

{% for i in ratings %}
 <div class="infinite-item">
     
<div class="w3-container w3-card w3-white w3-round w3-margin">
    <img src="{{ i.the_user.profile.avatar.url }}" alt="Avatar" class="w3-left w3-circle w3-margin-right" style="width:40px;height:40px;border-radius:50%;">

        <a href ="{% url 'profile' i.the_user_id %}" style="color:black;">{% with user=i.the_user.profile %}{{ user.prenom|title|truncatewords:2 }} {{ user.nom|title|truncatewords:1 }}{% endwith %}</a>
        <br>

       <span class="stars" data-rating="{{ i.vote.vote }}" data-num-stars="5" ></span>
        <hr class="w3-clear">
        <p>
        {{ i.commentaire|linebreaksbr }}
        </p>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> <a href ="{% url 'profile' i.the_sender_id %}">{% with user=i.the_sender.profile %}{{ user.prenom|title|truncatewords:2 }} {{ user.nom|title|truncatewords:1 }}{% endwith %}</a>
</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
   {% if ratings.has_next %}
    <a class="infinite-more-link" href="?page={{ ratings.next_page_number }}"></a>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
{% block rightcontent %}

{% endblock %}
{% block js %}
  <script>
    var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
      element: $('.infinite-container')[0]
    });
  </script>
<script>
//ES5
$.fn.stars = function() {
    return $(this).each(function() {
        var rating = $(this).data("rating");
        var fullStar = new Array(Math.floor(rating + 1)).join('<i class="fas fa-star"></i>');
        var halfStar = ((rating%1) !== 0) ? '<i class="fas fa-star-half-alt"></i>': '';
        var noStar = new Array(Math.floor($(this).data("numStars") + 1 - rating)).join('<i class="far fa-star"></i>');
        $(this).html(fullStar + halfStar + noStar);
    });
}

//ES6
$.fn.stars = function() {
    return $(this).each(function() {
        const rating = $(this).data("rating");
        const numStars = $(this).data("numStars");
        const fullStar = '<i class="fas fa-star"></i>'.repeat(Math.floor(rating));
        const halfStar = (rating%1!== 0) ? '<i class="fas fa-star-half-alt"></i>': '';
        const noStar = '<i class="far fa-star"></i>'.repeat(Math.floor(numStars-rating));
        $(this).html(`${fullStar}${halfStar}${noStar}`);
    });
}
</script>
<script>
            $(function(){
                $('.stars').stars();
            });
        </script>
{% endblock %}
```

I have tried to put the `<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` inside the `class="infinite-item"` but it does not help.what might be the reason for that ? Thanks.

Since yesterday I am on this question I tried everything.

This is another user that has tried to help me here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69930878/15042684 but I did not really understand could you please help me to understand it with some code.

this is his answer:

> It doesn't look like .stars() will look for new elements being added to the DOM. You should look for a callback function configuration option within Waypoint.Infinite that you can call .stars() on the new elements.

Comment: `$.fn.stars` *only* applies to elements that exist at the time the code runs.   If you add elements later, the code does not automatically pick up the new elements.  You need to run `$.fn.stars` on the new elements after they have been added to the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using waypoint's [Infinite Scroll](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/shortcuts/infinite-scroll/), you can use the `onAfterPageLoad` callback

> **onAfterPageLoad**
>
> Default: $.noop.
>
> Parameters: $items.
>
> This is a callback that will fire at the end of the request cycle, after new items have been appended to the container. It is passed one parameter, which is a jQuery object of all the items that were appended during the page load.

Note that despite using the jquery convention of `$name` indicates a jquery object and stating *is a jquery object*, in this case, trial and error shows that `$items` are the DOM elements, not a jquery object.

No example provided in the docs, so it will *probably* look something like:

```
  <script>
    var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
      element: $('.infinite-container')[0],
      onAfterPageLoad: function(items) {
          $(items).find(".stars").stars();
      } 
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: how can i pass the items to onAfterPageLoad: function ?i have tried your code but i am not seing the stars rating.

Comment: According to the (very limited) documentation, the newly generated elements are passed in as `$items` (`items)` in my code.  But I can't see from you code what that would be - try debugging the callback to see what you're actually getting.  Maybe it should be `items.filter(".stars").stars()` - maybe your infinite loader isn't loading any stars?

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your question and add working snippet in html/css/javascript(jquery)?   All the `{% %}` make it overly difficult to read.

Comment: this is the exception in my browser console `(index):221 Uncaught TypeError: items.find(...).stars is not a function
    at Object.onAfterPageLoad ((index):221)
    at t.<anonymous> (infinite.min.js:7)
    at Object.i [as success] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at u (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)`

Comment: Try `onAfterPageLoad: function(items) { $(items).find(".stars").stars(); }` as it looks like the return isn't a jquery object despite the practice of prefixing jquery objects with `$`.  Either that or your script tags are in the wrong order and you're blatting your `$.fn.stars`

Comment: Thank you very much.God bless you i finally solved it .this was the right function `onAfterPageLoad: function(items) { $(items).find(".stars").stars();` please try to update your answer.

Comment: can i ask you question please ?

Comment: You just did...   just ask.  If it's not related to this question or answer you'll probably be better off asking it as a new question as it will get better visibility.

Comment: yes it is related to this,i have the same trouble.i have post and when i load more post the like button is not working,before the load it is working well.

Comment: You need event delegation.  eg instead of `$(".btn").click(...` you need to use `$(document).on("click", ".btn", ...`  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) for more details.

Comment: can i invite you in a chat please ?

Comment: this is how my like button look like `<script>$('.likin').click(function(){......})
</script>` and my question now is how can i call on after page load without rewritting all the code inside the like click `$(items).find(".likin").'the-function-that-i-donot-know-how;`

Comment: Thank you and sorry for being so stupid.i tried out the link you sent me and it works fine Thank you again.